# Is there a way to enable command prompts 'quick edit' mode from the command line?

Tags: windows-10, command-line

Tired of having to right click and go to properties and enable quick edit. Is there a command I can run? a reg key I can modify from the cmd? 
Windows 10

Comment: In order to get to CMD properties in windows you have to open CMD and right click on the bar at the top of the window.

Comment: The setting should stick all by itself if you go to the cmd properties dialog.  You shouldn't need a registry hack.  I just tested this myself and it sticks to whatever I last left it at.

Comment: @SeñorCMasMas This is for work. I do help desk and we have over 200k machines we support. location 1 might have it but tomorrow ill need to remote into location 45000 and that wont be enabled there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a regkey in:

`Computer\HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Console`

There should be (or create it) a value `QuickEdit` of type `DWORD`, you can set it to 1.

Found it on: https://stackoverflow.com/a/9929239/2100126

Answer (score 0):

Already answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7941598/3000416), update "QuickMode" setting in Windows Registry:

```
reg add HKCU\Console /v QuickEdit /t REG_DWORD /d 0 /f
```

However it will not affect currently opened window. But you can reopen a window:

```
:: Get QuickEdit Mode setting from Windows Registry
FOR /F "usebackq tokens=3*" %%A IN (`REG QUERY "HKCU\Console" /v QuickEdit`) DO (
  set quickEditSetting=%%A %%B
)

if %quickEditSetting%==0x1 (
  :: Disable QuickEdit Mode
  reg add HKCU\Console /v QuickEdit /t REG_DWORD /d 0 /f

  :: Open script in a new Command Prompt window
  start "" "%~dpnx0" %* && exit
)

... script logic here ...
exit
```

Additional info about `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Console` Registry configuration - https://renenyffenegger.ch/notes/Windows/registry/tree/HKEY_CURRENT_USER/console/index